# EXCEL Grouping values based on Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
      Dates         Column 2    Column 3    Group By
17.02.2020 21:09:46    A          AA           1
17.02.2020 20:09:57    A          AB           2
17.02.2020 20:10:20    A          AB           2
17.02.2020 19:10:49    B          AC           3
17.02.2020 19:10:52    B          AC           3
17.02.2020 19:11:17    C          AD           4
17.02.2020 19:11:21    E          AD           5
```

Is it possible to group if Column 2 and Column 3 is matched and the date difference is < 1 minute. Above table is the expected scenario.

Comment: According sample Col 2 and Col 3 does not match. Grouping seems to have been done by duplicates in Col 3 only.
How is it right?

Comment: Hi Sorry, first time posting and the data got messed up. I have it corrected. Thank you for editing the table too.

Comment: Yes, it is. What do you expect for a result?

Comment: The expected result should be the values under the Group By Column. wherein it will group it by number and increment if it doesnt match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this is with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.  It does not require that the data be in any particular order.  And also can be refreshed easily if your data changes.

All of the steps can be done from the UI, except that entering the Custom column requires entering a formula in the appropriate dialog box

#### Alogrhythm

- Because I am in the US, your date/time stamps were interpreted as text by my system, so I required a step to `Change Type with Locale` which you may or may not require
- We then add a column which rounds the date/time to the nearest minute.

  - Formula:  `=Number.Round(Number.From([Dates])*24*60)/(24*60)`

[image]

- We select Columns 2,3 and our custom column and `Group By` without aggregation

[image]

- We then add another custom column to "break out" the original Dates column into a `List`

  - Formula: `=Table.Column([Grouped],"Dates")`

[image]

- We then remove the extra columns and reorder the Dates/List column to the beginning
- Add an Index column starting with 1
- Click on the double-arrow of the Dates column to expand to new rows
- I then changed the dates column type to DateTime.

[image]

#### M-Code

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", type text}, {"Column 2", type text}, {"Column 3", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Dates", type datetime}}, "en-150"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type with Locale", "Custom", each Number.Round(Number.From([Dates])*24*60)/(24*60)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Column 2", "Column 3", "Custom"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Dates=datetime, Column 2=text, Column 3=text, Custom=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Dates", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Dates")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom", "Grouped"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Dates", "Column 2", "Column 3"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Expanded Dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Index", "Dates"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Dates",{{"Dates", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

***Note:*** *For precise fidelity with your example, you can change the name of Index column to `Group By`*